# font-awesome icons not displaying

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, font-awesome

I installed the gem "font-awesome-sass" , and my static page is not loading the icons. Texts are appearing instead of the actual line

```
<li><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1g "></i> fa-twitter</li>
```

this is an example how i'm calling it.
I'm not sure where to go from here, since the guide to use font-awesome was pretty much installing the gem

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require it in the asset pipeline still

Put this in your application.css.scss

```
*= require font-awesome
```

Noted on the last line of their readme

https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass

Comment: im guessing this line goes in the stylesheet/custom.css file?

Comment: Sorry i updated it to say where, but yep in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss